# Angular HttpClient error handling difficult

Tags: json, angular, error-handling, httpclient

The Angular documentation on the new HttpClient 
https://angular.io/guide/http
has a section "Getting error details" where they show an example like below. I have modified to comments to document my observations which basic error classes end up where.

```
http
.get<ItemsResponse>('/api/items')
.subscribe(
  data => {...},
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
      // we never seem to get here
      console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
    } else {
      // no network connection, HTTP404, HTTP500, HTTP200 & invalid JSON
      console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
    }
  }
);
```

So at least 3 totally different categories of errors (network, http, response parsing) come in on a single channel and for each type one has to search for the actual reason in another part of HttpErrorResponse.

One can identify only one category, the HTTP errors through the standard error codes. But the other two types?

When I pull my network plug I get the extremely telling err.message = "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error." Very descriptive.

When the new internal JSON parsing fails it says that there is a syntax error - but not at what position/character (as returned by JSON.parse()). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621185/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-json-parsing-error-get-just-returns-null)

What about other errors like timeouts, etc.?

Where can I find documentation on this? Has anyone figured out a way to generally analyse this so one can give meaningful messages to the user?

Angular 5.2 in Chrome on Win, Backend: ASP.NET4.6.1 pure IHttpHandler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to look at the [Angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L157) to understand the possible error conditions. The error object will always be a `HttpErrorResponse`, but its `error` property may differ depending on the situation. Here's what can happen when using the default `XHRBackend` with the default `responseType` of `'json'`:

**Response received with HTTP status code indicating error (not 200-299):**

`HttpErrorResponse.error` will be the body parsed as JSON **or** if parsing fails, the body as text.

**Response received with good HTTP status code (200-299), but body could not be parsed as JSON:**

`HttpErrorResponse.error` will be an object typed as `HttpJsonParseError` with two properties:

- `error`: the parse error (of type `Error`)
- `text`: the body text

**No response received due to an XHR network error:**

`HttpErrorResponse.error` will be an XHR `ProgressEvent` with the type set to `'error'`. (It may be wrongly typed as an `ErrorEvent` in older versions of TypeScript.)

---

*Note*: Angular does not set a timeout when making requests, nor does it register a timeout event handler. The default XHR timeout is 0, so requests will never time out client-side.

Comment: Thanks eppsilon. Very elaborated answer. Partially because of the intransparency in error handling I have meanwhile switched to bare async .. await fetch() and am happy with it.