# Unable to get error message from API Angular 6

Tags: asp.net-core, angular6

I use the following function to Post a object of a given class.

```
public Post<T>(object: T, url: string, httpOptions: {}): Observable<T> {
return this.httpClient.post<T>(`${environment.apiEndpoint}` + url, object, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

}

This function is called in all the service that wants to post something. Like this.

```
public addEquipment(equipment: Equipment): Observable<Equipment> {
    return this.shared.Post<Equipment>(equipment, this.url, this.header);
}
```

addEquipment is then executed within the component that uses that service. Like this.

```
this.equipmentService.addEquipment(result)
    .subscribe((data: any) => { this.alertService.success(data) }, (error: any) => this.alertService.error(error));
```

The problem is when the API returns a error (that I can see includes a error message, in the network tab) it tells me that there is no body in the response. The API returns a HttpResult where the error message is added to the response field.

```
return new HttpResult { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Conflict, Response = "Error message"}
```

I use the following function to handle the errors.

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
  console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
}
else {
  console.log(error);
  console.error(
    `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
    `body was: ${error.error}`);
}
console.log(error);
return throwError(
  error.error)
};
```

It is Angular 6 and a ServiceStack API. 
All suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FYI it's preferable to return structured error responses in ServiceStack which you can do with:

```
HttpError.Conflict("Error message");
```

Which will let you catch it when using [ServiceStack's TypeScript ServiceClient](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference) with:

```
try {
    var response = await client.post(request);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.responseStatus.message);
}
```

But from this answer for [handling errors with Angular HTTP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46019852/85785) it suggests the error body should be accessible with:

```
this.httpClient
  .get("data-url")
  .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    // simple logging, but you can do a lot more, see below
    console.error('An error occurred:', err.error);
  });
```

Comment: I see, I will take a look at the ServiceClient. However, the solution you gave, isn't that pretty much what I do? I just use a function instead? I get the HttpErrorResponse, it just doesn't have the response within it. In my specific case I get "409 Conflict" and not "Equipment already exists"

Comment: 409 Conflict sounds like it's coming from the Status Description not the response body. Can't speak to the error you're seeing but from everything I see `HttpErrorResponse.error` should [contain the body parsed as JSON or the body as text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52085631/85785)

Comment: Yes, when I return HttpResult { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Accepted, Response="Added"} I get the response, but when I try to do the same for 409, I only get conflict, which for me does not make any sense.. looking at you guys Client now, and I think that I will start to use that instead.

Comment: How would you make the client work for Template functions? When I pass the object into the post, it does not work.

Comment: @AtleKristiansen I've no idea on what you're referring to, please post a new question with full details, where the issue is, including raw HTTP Request/Response headers.